# Django 'related_name' validation error with User

Tags: django

In my project, I'm getting an error in my models.py when I added a model that uses a ForeignKey w/ User and a 'related_name'. For example:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='id_of_the_follower')
who_following = models.ForeignKey('User', related__name='id_of_the_person_being_followed')
pubdate = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-pubdate']
```

The error I get is:

```
lobby.follow: 'follower' has a relation with model User, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
lobby.follow: 'who_following' has a relation with model User, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

I have imported my User database with:
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User

Models.py validates just fine with my other models that have User as a ForeignKey but don't use 'related_name' but it keeps throwing me errors when I have a related_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: You've written "related_name" ("who_following" field) keyword with double underscore. It's wrong!

---

As long as you is using "django.contrib.auth" you should refer to User model like this:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
        related_name='id_of_the_follower')
    who_following = models.ForeignKey('auth.User',
        related_name='id_of_the_person_being_followed')
```

or you can refer  to model User explicitly:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey(User,
        related_name='id_of_the_follower')
    who_following = models.ForeignKey(User,
        related_name='id_of_the_person_being_followed')
```

However, if you want to reference the "user" model from other app in your project, you should do something like:

```
class Follow(models.Model):
    follower = models.ForeignKey("yourappname.User",
        related_name='id_of_the_follower')
    who_following = models.ForeignKey("yourappname.User",
        related_name='id_of_the_person_being_followed')
```

Comment: You're right, I had two underscores on the related_name. Thanks!